# ASP.Net Forms Authentication cookie is passed across sessions

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, formsauthentication

I am fairly new with developing in ASP.Net and I've searched high and low for a resolution to this, to no avail. I am using Forms Authentication to authenticate users and when I login with user A, I abandon the current session, generate a new session cookie/id and redirect from to my content page and everything works as planned. However, when I open a new browser window and navigate to the login screen, thus starting a new session, the authentication cookie for user A is automatically passed to this session and is part of the request cookies collection. Even worse, when I actually log in as user B and get a new authentication cookie then refresh the browser window for session A, it now has the authentication cookie of user B.

I have no idea why this is happening. I thought the browser (IE9) was caching the authentication cookie because the response-header collection is set to cache-control "private" even though I specifically set the Response.Cache.SetCacheability("no-cache") in my code-behind for all pages. Then I was thinking it could be a threading issue.

Any insight into why this is happening is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Add some code. How are you "abandoning the current session"?

Comment: @Zerkey After I authenticate the user's credentials, I create an authentication ticket/cookie then issue Session.Abandon(). Next, I Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie("sessionID", "")), in order to clear the cookie. Then I use the Session Manager to generate a new session ID and cookie,  i.e SessionManager.SaveSessionID(Context, NewSessionID, redirected, IsAdded). This works just fine, when the user logs in, he is redirected to my content page with a new session ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try different Browsers like Chrome and IE. Because browser share same cookie and temp file even opened in new windows. Above scenario will occur if you try with gmail.com or live.com.

Comment: After testing the scenario with gmail.com, you're completely right. The newest user authentication cookie replaces the old user's, thus logging the old user out. How do I prevent this? Ultimately, I want to get to a point where if user's login from 2 different windows/sessions, the older session is invalidated. I know I need to do something like                    If Request.IsAuthenticated AndAlso Not System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache(User.Identity.Name) = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID Then Session.Abandon but the user is authenticated before logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config files for session settings.

Check out the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.enablecrossappredirects.aspx